# cfdisk showing more than 4 partitions

Tags: linux, partition, disk, lfs, cfdisk

I was **trying to make a swap partition**, but an error message came saying

```
Primary Partition Not Available
```

I checked the internet and found out there can't be more than 4 partitions because Linux only has room for 4 by default (for some reason). But I can see there's a **sda5** in my partition table.

```
   /dev/sda1                                                                   229474304                    230518783                      1044480                      510M                    27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
    Free space                                                                  230518784                    230520831                         2048                        1M
    /dev/sda2                                                                   230520832                    934482553                    703961722                    335.7G                     7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sda3                                                                   934483966                    976771071                     42287106                     20.2G                     5 Extended
    └─/dev/sda5                                                                 934483968                    976771071                     42287104                     20.2G                    83 Linux
    /dev/sda4                                                                        2048                     20973567                     20971520                       10G                    83 Linux
```

How is there more than 4 primary partitions? Is sda5 even a primary partition? Why is sda5 looking like a branch of sda3? Please point me towards the right direction.

(I just wanted to make a swap partition, since LFS is recommending, DO I even need a swap partition when I have 8GB RAM?)

Comment: A Primary partition can contain (unsurprisingly) secondary partitions. sda5 is a secondary, and you can create many (I have 5 inside my /dev/sda3). The restriction to 4 is a result of a Microsoft decision which is tangled up with the boot mechanism.

Comment: To be more precise, the old MBR (or DOS, as it is also called) partition table from the 1980s has a size of 64 bytes (not a typo). It resides at the end of the first 512-bytes-block on the disk. Since each partition is described by 16 bytes, only 4 primary partitions are possible. `sda3` on this particular disk is used as a container for an additional partition table elsewhere on the disk, which has enough room for plenty of secondary partitions. All that becomes a non-issue if you use the modern (i.e. not even 30 years old) GPT format instead of MBR.

Comment: The need of swap does not depend on the size of RAM alone. It depends on the workload. Since your system is most probably experimental without running much, you can probably live without swap space.

Comment: That was very informative @berndbausch, exactly what I needed.

Comment: thank you @Paul_Pedant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/dev/sda5` is an extended partition (aka logical partition), hence it looks like a branch. Yes, that is true, Linux supports only four physical partitions. Your system already have four physical partitions. You can use `cfdisk` command to create a new logical partition (`/dev/sda6`) and use that for swap

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that effort, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Linux supports as many partitions as fit the disk. MBR partition tables have 4 entries, no matter which operating system uses the disk, Windows, BSD, Linux, etc. GPT partition tables have at least 128 entries according to the UEFI standard, and that's what Linux supports, too.